# How to update period of a timer every interrupt on stm32 with preload enabled?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, c, timer, interrupts

I'd like to change timer period  inside interrupt handler that is equivalent to AVR code `ISR(TIMER0_COMP_vect){ OCR0 == new_value }` As I undestand the documentation, ARR register value change due to shadowing is applied when update event is generated, that in counting mode happens either when CNT register value reaches the previous value in ARR register, or when UG bit is set in EGR register programmatically. Setting UG bit generates update event but doesn't generate interrupt (no UIF flag set).

My problem is that I cannot get how to use this "doubledecker" of preload and shadow registers properly. Below is a program that at even (0,2,4...) interrupts turns a LED off, at at odd (1,3,5...) turns it on. If I do it with preloader disabled everything is rather straightforward:

```
//Initialization
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_7,GPIO_PIN_SET);

RCC -> APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_TIM2EN; //for my l152re tim2 is timed from apb1
TIM2->SMCR &= ~TIM_SMCR_SMS; //timing from abp1
TIM2->CR1 &= ~TIM_CR1_ARPE; //disable autoreload
TIM2->PSC = 31999; //1000 us/tick
TIM2->ARR = 19999; //LED will be on for 20sec till first interrupt 

TIM2->EGR |= TIM_EGR_UG; /*Without that interrupt fires immediately, see this answer (electronics.stackexchange.com/a/161982/297176) and comments */
TIM2->SR &= ~ TIM_SR_UIF; //Just to be sure
TIM2->DIER |= TIM_DIER_UIE; //Enable TIM2 interupt 
NVIC_EnableIRQ (TIM2_IRQn); //Enable TIM2 interrupt in NVIC
TIM2 -> CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN; //Start timer in forward counting mode

//Handler
void TIM2_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_IRQn 0 */
  TIM2->CR1 &= ~TIM_CR1_CEN; //Stop count. Not really necessary
  if ((TIM2->SR & TIM_SR_UIF) == TIM_SR_UIF){
      HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_7);
      uint16_t delay = TIM2->ARR;
      sprintf(buf, "Passed period %d\r\n", delay);
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)buf, strlen(buf), strlen(buf)/8);
      delay /=2;
      TIM2->ARR = delay;
   TIM2->SR &= ~ TIM_SR_UIF; //Clear interrupt flag
   }
TIM2->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN; //Continue count
}
```

Here I get exactly the needed behavior. How I should write the code with autoreload enabled?

Comment: what is it that you want to accomplish , or think will happen, when you implement ARPE ? In other words what will be different about how your program behaves if you have ARPE enabled ? I just want to better understand the problem because if the  above code works fine then I do not understand the added benefit of auto preload. Since you are already in an update event , my understanding was that auto preload helped to make you changes instant if you so happen to not be in an update event but if youre in the ISR youre already in the update event ..

Comment: According to reference manual with preload periods are more precise. I'd like to use a single timer to control several servos or steppers or a single stepper going at maximum speed and 256 microsteps. Or change PSC that seems to be always buffered. Of course, I will not stop counting at interrupt enter. There is a thing I cannot figure out - chain of interrupt, update event and shadow register update. As I get it event goes first, then register update and only then we enter interrupt handler with next period unchangeable if ARPE is set. If that's right, we should think two steps ahead.